# Arabic output in python 3 is stored weirdly in a file

Tags: python, selenium

I made a small web scraping bot using Python 3, Currently it is taking the input between  classes and thankfully puts them into .csv file, But when i open it i find the part in arabic letters of it like this:
ÙˆØ§Ø¦Ù„ ÙØªÙ

I tried arabic resharper but looks like it just does converting in direction and some sort of encoding, When storing the string it represent bad characters as same as the above

Also this code below makes a successful arabic content into text file:

```
s = "ذهب الطالب الى المدرسة"
with open("file.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as myfile:
    myfile.write(s)
```

-Note i'm using Selenium driver to get the content:

```
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(content.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Thank you for help, But the things came out correctly, It was problem with the program that opened my .csv files (excel in this case) and i found the solution and i will post it

Answer (score 0):

Answer after more digging into problem:
1- I found that if i open it with normal windows notepad - i can see the arabic content so python was producing the website content correctly!
2- I used this video as a reference to correctly show data in excel (which the problem was in):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6AR_Hi7p5Q